# Sort a numpy matrix based on its diagonal

Tags: python, matrix, numpy, scipy

I have a matrix that should have ones on the diagonal but the columns are mixed up.

[image: Messed up matrix]

But I don't know how, without the obvious for loop, to efficiently interchange rows to get unity on the diagonals. I'm not even sure what key I would pass to sort on.

Any suggestions?

Comment: since they're floats, can you guarantee the ones are exactly 1.0 and unique in their columns?

Comment: @wim: There is the issue of floating point error. But, each entry along the diagonal is guaranteed to have the highest value in that row.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use numpy's [`argmax`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html#numpy.argmax) to determine the goal column ordering and reorder your matrix using the argmax results as column indices:

```
>>> z = numpy.array([[ 0.1 ,  0.1 ,  1.  ],
...                  [ 1.  ,  0.1 ,  0.09],
...                  [ 0.1 ,  1.  ,  0.2 ]])

numpy.argmax(z, axis=1)

>>> array([2, 0, 1]) #Goal column indices

z[:,numpy.argmax(z, axis=1)]

>>> array([[ 1.  ,  0.1 ,  0.1 ],
...        [ 0.09,  1.  ,  0.1 ],
...        [ 0.2 ,  0.1 ,  1.  ]])
```

Comment: Very nice. For a 1000x1000 array, yours runs in 0.1s and mine runs in 10s.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[ 1. ,  0.5,  0.5,  0. ],
...               [ 0.5,  0.5,  1. ,  0. ],
...               [ 0. ,  1. ,  0. ,  0.5],
...               [ 0. ,  0.5,  0.5,  1. ]])
>>> np.array(sorted(a, cmp=lambda x, y: list(x).index(1) - list(y).index(1)))
array([[ 1. ,  0.5,  0.5,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  1. ,  0. ,  0.5],
       [ 0.5,  0.5,  1. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0.5,  0.5,  1. ]])
```

It actually sorts by rows, not columns (but the result is the same). It works by sorting by the index of the column the `1` is in.

Comment: The standard library wins again. Any way to do this without having to use numpy lists? I can imagine this being fairly slow for a large array.

Comment: @jozzas: It actually doesn't rely on numpy at all. It'll work fine if you take out the `np.array` parts.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the python lists. Is there a numpy-only solution?

Comment: @jozzas: I didn't see an obvious numpy-only solution. Maybe someone else can come up with one.

Comment: I think I've got one, don't know that it's much better than this though.

Comment: @Snowball +1 for an elegant solution. I chose jozzas' as the answer because it is "numpy-only". Still, I could imagine cases where your solution would come in very handy.