# How to swap array elements on C language and integrate it to code?

Tags: c, arrays, matrix

I have a problem with changing arrays and integrating them into my code, the task is

> "Given a real square matrix of order n. Find the smallest of the values ​​of the elements located in the shaded part of the matrix and swap them.
>
> [image]"

I figured out the first half of the code, but I can’t figure it out with the second part, that is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define N 5

int main ()
{
    int a[N][N], min, i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
            a[i][j] = rand () % 10;
    }
    printf ("n\n The generated matrix has the form");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
            printf ("%d  ", a[i][j]);
        printf ("\n");
    }
    min = a[0][N - 1];
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (j = N / 2; j < N; j++)
            if ((j + i) > N && (i <= j) && (min > a[i][j]))
                min = a[i][j];
    }
    printf ("n\n Minimum element in the shaded area");
    printf ("\n\n min_element=%d ", min);
    getch ();
}
```

Comment: Can you please format this? At least one space per scope would be nice, but four is great.

Comment: Is "swap them" the part you want to do? It's not clear what to swap with what. Maybe add an example for matrix of size 4x4 and 5x5? You can [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: I mean Change the values ​​of the elements represented in the shaded part of the matrix. this is 5x5 matrix, the result was 1.(1 7 4 0 9), 2.(4 8 8 2 4), 3.(5 5 1 7 1), 4.(1 5 2 7 6),   5.(1 4 2 3 2)

Comment: @Ramazan I have not understood what to swap. Place in your question an example of the original matrix and the matrix after swapping the smallest values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is a bit confused. You must seed the random number generator by calling `srand()` before calling `rand()`, e.g.

```
#include <time.h>
...
int main (void) {

    int a[N][N], min = INT_MAX, i, j;

    srand (time(NULL));             /* seed random number generator */
```

(**note:** how `min` is initialized to `INT_MAX`)

You can fill and output your original array in a single loop. Note, `% 10` results in `0` in all quadrants regularly, use `% 100` for a greater range of values, e.g.

```
    /* fill elements with random values 0-99, output array */
    puts ("\nThe generated matrix has the form:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            a[i][j] = rand () % 100;
            printf ("  %2d", a[i][j]);
        }
        putchar ('\n');
    }
```

(**note:** don't use `printf ("\n");` to output the single character `'\n'`, that is what `putchar('\n');` is for -- though a good compiler will make that optimization for you)

You can compare the values in the upper and lower triangles in a single loop, e.g.:

```
    for (i = 0; i < N - i; i++) {           /* loop rows 0 - N-i-1 */
        for (j = i; j < N - i; j++) {       /* loop cols i - N-i-1 */
            if (a[i][j] < min)              /* test upper value */
                min = a[i][j];
            if (a[N-i-1][j] < min)          /* test lower value */
                min = a[N-i-1][j];
        }
    }
```

You only need a single `printf` to output the result, whether you do it like:

```
    printf ("\nMinimum element in the shaded area\n\n  min_element = %d\n", min);
```

or like

```
    printf ("\nMinimum element in the shaded area\n\n"
            "  min_element = %d\n", min);
```

Lastly do not use `conio.h` and `getch();` to hold the terminal window open. `conio.h` is an archaic DOS header that is 100% non-portable. Simply use `getchar()` which is provided by the standard `<stdio.h>`.

Putting it altogether you would have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <time.h>

#define N 5

int main (void) {

    int a[N][N], min = INT_MAX, i, j;

    srand (time(NULL));             /* seed random number generator */

    /* fill elements with random values 0-99, output array */
    puts ("\nThe generated matrix has the form:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            a[i][j] = rand () % 100;
            printf ("  %2d", a[i][j]);
        }
        putchar ('\n');
    }

    for (i = 0; i < N - i; i++) {           /* loop rows 0 - N-i-1 */
        for (j = i; j < N - i; j++) {       /* loop cols i - N-i-1 */
            if (a[i][j] < min)              /* test upper value */
                min = a[i][j];
            if (a[N-i-1][j] < min)          /* test lower value */
                min = a[N-i-1][j];
        }
    }

    printf ("\nMinimum element in the shaded area\n\n  min_element = %d\n", min);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/array_upper_lower_triangle

The generated matrix has the form:

  20  79  30  60  89
   2   5  38  15  33
  64  63  52  93  38
  77  89  54  38  89
  25  15  87  43  53

Minimum element in the shaded area

  min_element = 5
```

**Edit -- Swapping Min From Upper/Lower Triangles**

After seeing your comment, it also became clear you want to swap the minimum elements from the upper and lower triangles. To do so, you need to keep separate minimums, like `min_upper` and `min_lower` as well as the array indexes where they occur, like `iu, ju` (for `i` & `j` upper) and `il`, `jl` for lower.

Then after finding the minimums in each you can swap them. The changes would be:

```
    int a[N][N], min, min_upper=INT_MAX, min_lower=INT_MAX, i, j, iu, ju, il, jl;
    ...
    for (i = 0; i < N - i; i++) {           /* loop rows 0 - N-i */
        for (j = i; j < N - i; j++) {       /* loop cols i - N-i-1 */
            if (a[i][j] < min_upper) {      /* test upper value */
                min_upper = a[i][j];
                iu = i, ju = j;
            }
            if (a[N-i-1][j] < min_lower) {  /* test lower value */
                min_lower = a[N-i-1][j];
                il = N-i-1, jl = j;
            }
        }
    }
    i = a[iu][ju];              /* swap uppwer/lower triangle minimum values */
    a[iu][ju] = a[il][jl];
    a[il][jl] = i;
```

(**note:** `i` is used as the temporary variable in the swap since it is available between loops)

The complete example with the swap would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <time.h>

#define N 5

int main (void) {

    int a[N][N], min, min_upper=INT_MAX, min_lower=INT_MAX, i, j, iu, ju, il, jl;

    srand (time(NULL));             /* seed random number generator */

    /* fill elements with random values 0-99, output array */
    puts ("\nThe generated matrix has the form:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            a[i][j] = rand () % 100;
            printf ("  %2d", a[i][j]);
        }
        putchar ('\n');
    }

    for (i = 0; i < N - i; i++) {           /* loop rows 0 - N-i */
        for (j = i; j < N - i; j++) {       /* loop cols i - N-i-1 */
            if (a[i][j] < min_upper) {      /* test upper value */
                min_upper = a[i][j];
                iu = i, ju = j;
            }
            if (a[N-i-1][j] < min_lower) {  /* test lower value */
                min_lower = a[N-i-1][j];
                il = N-i-1, jl = j;
            }
        }
    }
    i = a[iu][ju];              /* swap uppwer/lower triangle minimum values */
    a[iu][ju] = a[il][jl];
    a[il][jl] = i;

    printf ("\nmin_upper : %d\nmin_lower : %d\n", min_upper, min_lower);

    puts("\nSwapped min from upper/lower triangles:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
            printf ("  %2d", a[i][j]);
        putchar ('\n');
    }

    min = min_upper < min_lower ? min_upper : min_lower;

    printf ("\nMinimum element in the shaded area\n\n  min_element = %d\n", min);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/array_upper_lower_triangle_swap

The generated matrix has the form:

  31  52  50  21  40
  48  63  65  15  48
  77  70  69  90  18
  56  22  36  71  14
  13  14  53  26  32

min_upper : 15
min_lower : 13

Swapped min from upper/lower triangles:

  31  52  50  21  40
  48  63  65  13  48
  77  70  69  90  18
  56  22  36  71  14
  15  14  53  26  32

Minimum element in the shaded area

  min_element = 13
```

Hopefully that meets all your requirements. If you need more help, just ask.

Comment: Ohhh dude thank you I had a problem that the random numbers didn’t go out but the same ones came out, I got confused about all this, where I have been living already 5 in the morning and I haven’t slept all this time, but the original problem remains, I need to change the values ​​of the elements located in the shaded part of the matrix. can you help with this?

Comment: Hold on, I also have an edit to swapping the min from upper and lower I'll post in a second. Good luck with your coding!

Comment: @Ramazan - Updated with example code for swapping minimum elements between upper and lower triangle regions.

Comment: If you need to swap all elements, just declare a new temporary `int` within the loop and swap each element with each iteration -- I was unclear on whether you just needed to swap the minimum values or every value from top to bottom. Either way it works the same -- and you don't have to keep separate minimums if you swap every element -- let me know if you get stuck if that is what you need to do.

Comment: I will try to swap all the elements for the sake of interest, but first I need to sleep, it was a long day)))) thank you, if I have any difficulties I will write to you right away;)

Comment: Hey its me again, can you help with the second part of my task, in the second part is "
Develop a block diagram and compose a program for sorting matrix elements: a) sort the elements of the side diagonal by a simple exchange method; b) sort the elements of the main diagonal using the simple sampling method; c) elements of the first row are sorted by simple insertion, All this should be inserted into the code that you show me that time

Comment: That looks like a good trip through the different sorting routines. For the diagonals, you can look at [Sort matrix based on its diagonal entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36381356/sort-matrix-based-on-its-diagonal-entries) for the left/right triangles, that essentially is just the elements left-over that we don't index in the upper/lower triangles (what I suggest is just reading the left triangle entries into a temporary 1D array, sort that, then just write the sorted elements back to your 2D array (same for the right), first row, you can just handle as a 1D array -- give it a go.

Comment: Good job! There is nothing like coding up what seemed impossible a few days ago -- and it *Works!* Learning C is a journey, not a race, enjoy it. It's not something you will do in a semester or year -- or frankly ever (they tweak the standard from time to time). Approach it the same way you would eat a whale -- one byte at a time. Pay attention to each byte and you will soon be the one providing answers here `:)`